# Get value from GridView when a button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView , and the GridView has an item template. Now I need to get the value of the first cell which contains the value I need but I have tried the following and does not work, it eturns a ""

```
 int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text);
```

Here is the code I have in the gridview

```
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDepartmentID" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DepartmentID")%>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
      </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have to emphazise that I do not want to use the GridView_RowCommand or other GridView events.. I need to pull this value upon clicking a button on the same page.

How can I do this?

Comment: where is this code under then? the int id line. Also, are you using the object type **Gridview** in the code?? is the GridView object named something else? Like GridView1 or something?

Comment: the line of code is in a btn_Click event. Now usinf the Gridview object, the Gridview is named GridView1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access the text value of `Label` then you have to first get the reference to `Label` control like this:

```
Label lbl = (Label)GridView.Rows[index].FindControl("lblDepartmentID");
```

and then use it's `Text` property to get the value required:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(lbl.Text);
```